# two close buttons on one popup in codedrop window effect plugin

Tags: jquery

I am using http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/ plugin in my website. I want to use two close buttons on one popup but only one is working, not both. How can I make both close buttons work.

Answer (score 0):

Add `class="md-close"` to your span

```
<span id="cda-remove" class="md-close"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two close button  popup

```
<div class="md-modal md-effect-1" id="modal-1">
        <div class="md-content">
            <h3>Modal Dialog</h3>
           <button class="md-close-custom">Close me!</button>
            <div>
                <p>This is a modal window. You can do the following things with it:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><strong>Read:</strong> modal windows will probably tell you something important so don't forget to read what they say.</li>
                    <li><strong>Look:</strong> a modal window enjoys a certain kind of attention; just look at it and appreciate its presence.</li>
                    <li><strong>Close:</strong> click on the button below to close the modal.</li>
                </ul>
                <button class="md-close">Close me!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Write own jQuery function to close our custom close button

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('.md-close-custom').click(function () {
            $('.md-close').submit();
        });

    </script>
```